# Cancelling factor in fractions with factorial

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

My goal is to make a simplification:

$$\frac{k}{k!} \to \frac{1}{(k-1)!}.$$

However, $k$ in the denominator and numerator is not automatically cancelled by Mathematica.

What is the best known method to get $1/(k-1)!$ for the following two cases?

**(Case 1)**

```
k/k!
```

**(Case 2)**

```
((k (1 - x)^(-k + n) x^(-1 + k) n!)/(k! (-k + n)!))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rule = Factorial[k] :> (k Factorial[k - 1])
```

This way only `k!` will be affected.

```
expr = {k/k!, ((k (1 - x)^(-k + n) x^(-1 + k) n!)/(k! (-k + n)!))}

TraditionalForm@expr
TraditionalForm /@ expr /. rule
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do it without replacement rules in the cases discussed here.

Consider

```
exp1 = k/k!;
exp2 = ((k (1 - x)^(-k + n) x^(-1 + k) n!)/(k! (-k + n)!));
```

One suggestion:

```
Simplify`SimplifyGamma@exp1
Simplify`SimplifyGamma@exp2
```

Another is:

```
Developer`GammaSimplify@exp1
Developer`GammaSimplify@exp2
```

The results of the above are the same as in the solution suggested by @Syed

> [image: res]

Comment: I consider this method to be the best. Recently I needed to simplify expressions like `(n-5)!/(n-2)!` in one long recurrence and since FullSimplify didn't help, I had to do it manually. With this it works fine!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
FullSimplify[k/k!, k > 0] 
(* 1/Gamma[k] *)

FullSimplify [Gamma[k] == (k - 1)!, Element[k, PositiveIntegers]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For k/k! , it worked. However for the case 2(I've just appended to the question), FullSimplify function didn't show the effect of eliminating common factor.

Comment: @Soon Don't know how to do that for case 2. Perhaps try rule based solution (see Syed's answer)